# Should I initialize a floating-point (double,float) variable with 0 or 0.0?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, initialization, ieee-754

My question is: 
Should i initialize a floating-point variable like a `double` or `float` with `0` or rather `0.0` (if i want to initialize it with a value equivalent to `0` of course)?

Like for example:

```
double var = 0.0;
```

in comparison to:

```
double var = 0;
```

Does it make a difference?

---

Question is open for C and C++, as i work with both and did not want to make the same question twice. If there is a significant difference between those two with regards to especially that case, please mention which language is in your focus.

With the half eye on C++, the case of the constructor might become also an influence to the topic and of course initialization in general is a broader topic in C++, but i don´t know whether this is influencing the answer or not.

Huge thanks.

Comment: It does not make any difference, but might demonstrate the intention for the reader.

Comment: Try both, look at the generated code, and see what (if any) differences it makes.

Comment: `0.0` is a `double` value. `0` is an integer number that will be implicitly converted to a `double` value when you assign it to `var`. Some tools for static code analysis may print a warning for this.

Comment: It makes no difference in this case.  That said, if you have something like `std::vector<double> foo = stuff; std::accumulate(foo.begin(), foo.end(), 0);` it makes a big difference as now `accumulate` uses an `int` instead of a `double`.  Because of this, use the literal that matches the type and it should lead to less issues.

Comment: My initial reaction is that there is no difference, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's bad advice.  Just because a particular compiler generates code one way doesn't mean the standard requires it to be that way.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Thank you very much for this advice, Nathan.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica No problem.  I like to use auto a lot so I kind of "avoid" the problem by just using `auto var = 0.0;` and now I know I have a zeroed double.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica That's fine for double, int, ... For types from `cstdint` header, this looks far less appropriate to me, we'd quickly get non-portable that way (wanting `uint32_t`, writing `7u`, but on next machine int is only 16 bits. Fine, let's use `7ul` then – and I get uint64_t instead on my machine...). Apart from, `unsigned long n = 7;` even with lacking suffix looks clearer to me than `auto n = 7ul;` (suffix can be overlooked more easily).

Comment: @Aconcagua That's what user defined literals are for.  define a `std::uint32_t operator "" _u32` and then you use `auto foo  = 0_u32;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Actually I would have expected the standard to provide these... Still I consider `unsigned long n = 7` superior to `auto n = 7ul` (my last example before).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @NathanOliver comments, it doesn't make a difference *in this case*.  But it's a good habit to always say what you mean:

```
double var = 0.0;
```

Where this habit will pay off is places like `std::accumulate`:

```
std::vector<double> v{1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 6.7, 7.8, 8.9, 9.0, 10.1};

double sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);  // 0 here is wrong!
```

this isn't going to work as `std::accumulate` is declared as:

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
constexpr T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );
```

so the `0` causes `T` to be `int`!

Comment: Congratulations on finding a use case where there is an actual difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom Found it the hard way and have been diligent with my `0`s and `0.0`s ever since! :--)

Comment: Hm, actually, Nathan was a bit faster to dig that out (see comments to question) – so his laurels?

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, he commented before I answered but to be honest it was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: I think we've all been burned by `std::accumulate`.  It's a design that is non-intuitive and harmful IMHO.

Comment: @PaulEvans Thank you very much, Paul. Doesn´t mind if you were first. This world would be a lot harder without the knowledge of the pros of yours. Thank you all.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Quite right! It should use the iterator `value_type`.

Answer (score 2):

A double you can just initialize like this:

```
double test = 0.0;
```

However, a float you have to initialize like this if you want to do it 100% correct:

```
float test = 0.0f;
```

The `f` means that the number that precedes it is a float. If you leave it out, the number is interpreted as a double and automatically casted back to a float because your variable is of type float. Leaving the `f` out doesn't cause any real trouble but it introduces unnecessary overhead. I believe something similar happens when you initialize a double with just 0 instead of 0.0, but I am not sure about this part.

Comment: Overhead? At least not at run-time, the conversion is done already while compiling; what would happen inside the compiler I cannot tell, though...

Comment: @Anteino Thank you very much for your answer, Anteino. I did not know that a floating point value is automatically interpreted as `double` value neither that there is a convention to use a format specifier trailing a numeric constant. Do you got a reference for that? Maybe the respective section in the standard? That would be great.

Comment: Hey man, thanks and no problem. A teacher told me this once in a lecture. I will try to find the reference or ask him about it if I can't find it.

Comment: You do not need to put such hard efforts in it. I do not want to molest you. Thank you very much for your help and the tip with that anyway. I´ll go on research for that too, ;-) Thank you very much.

Comment: No it's okay, now I want to know.
My professor says he is not sure wether this overhead is introduced at compile time or not. For this I will have to check the assembly code. I will edit my answer as I find out more.

Comment: If a compiler didn't optimize the double constant `0.0` to float `0.0f` automatically at compile time, I would consider it defective. There should be absolutely no overhead.  Same with initializing with int `0`.